# How can I add time and date to a query output file name in sql server agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs, files

I have a query set up in SQL Server agent to return an output result file. The problem I have is how to set a date and time stamp so that the file name always includes the date and time.

On the SQL Agent Job, I opened step and clicked on the "Advanced" tab, then I selected a file path where the output should be saved and that's all.

Comment: Thank you @AMtwo On the SQL agent Job i opened step and clicked on Advance then I selected a file path where the output should be saved and that all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SQL Agent Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-ver16) in step output filenames to include the date and time. The macros that might be useful are:

- DATE
- TIME
- STRTTM
- STRTDT

Comment: I Appreciate, this worked for me.